# Highest and Lowest in Python through CodeWars. Unknown syntax error

Tags: python

The instructions:
In this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.

Example:

```
high_and_low("1 2 3 4 5")  # return "5 1"
high_and_low("1 2 -3 4 5") # return "5 -3"
high_and_low("1 9 3 4 -5") # return "9 -5"
```

Notes:

All numbers are valid Int32, no need to validate them.
There will always be at least one number in the input string.
Output string must be two numbers separated by a single space, and highest number is first.

Here is my code:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    for number in numbers:
        if number is None: 
            largest = int(number)
        if int(number) > largest:
            int(number) = largest
        if number is None:
            smallest = int(number)
        if int(number) < smallest:
            smallest = int(number)
     return largest" "smallest
```

This is my error:

```
File "<string>", line 20
return largest" "smallest 
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What in the world am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Return a string? Use `str.format`. `return '{} {}'.format(largest, smallest)`

Comment: That's a pretty obvious syntax error, yes. What did you expect that expression to do?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thought after iterating through the numbers it would return the largest and smallest value.

Comment: ohhhh after closer examination, realized the numbers that are input do not have commas. going to have to go thru this some more. thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below instructions instead of `return largest" "smallest` :

```
...
res = "{}  {}".format(largest, smallest)
return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is mentioned that all numbers are space separated and valid int, you can use-

`[int(num )for num in numbers.split(' ')]`